# Automating for loop between multiple subarrays in Python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, sub-array

I have multiple `dbf` files in a directory that I am trying to loop through and convert into excel files. However, because the loop times out after running for a while I divided the array list into ten subarrays of the same size.

```
import arcpy
import os
import glob
from arcpy.sa import *
from arcpy import env
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

dbf_filenames = sorted(glob.glob("*.dbf"))

# Split the array into ten equal parts
pieces = 10
new_arrays = np.array_split(dbf_filenames, pieces)

# Set
array_list = new_arrays[0]

for file in array_list:
   basefilename = os.path.basename(file)

    # Name of File
    CleanBaseStr = os.path.splitext(basefilename)[0]

    # Create Variable for Year
    yearmonth = os.path.splitext(basefilename)[0][16:22]

    # Create Variable for Gage Number
    Gage = '_'.join(CleanBaseStr.split('_')[1:-1])
    # print(Gage)

    # Create New Field
    field_name = "Year_Month"
    field_type = "DOUBLE"

    field = ["Year_Month"]
    # arcpy.management.DeleteField(file, field)
    arcpy.management.AddField(file, field_name, field_type, field_length = 6)

    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(file, field) as cursor:

        try:
            for row in cursor:
                # print (row)
                row[0] = yearmonth
                cursor.updateRow(row)

                ### Execute table to excel
                # Name Excel file
                out_xls = CleanBaseStr + ".xlsx"
                output_file = os.path.join(path,out_xls)

                # Open dbf files
                new_df = Dbf5(file)

                # Conver dbf to databframe
                df = new_df.to_dataframe()
                df['Year_Month'] = yearmonth
                # print(df)

                # Save dataframe to excel
                df.to_excel(output_file)

        except:
            continue
```

The loop works as I want it to, but I would like to know if there is a way to automate the for loop to move between the subarrays rather than doing the change manually. Currently, I am waiting for the loop to finish and then manually changing the subarrays from`new_arrays[0]` to `new_arrays[1]` and so forth until I reach the last subarray `new_arrays[9]`.

Comment: I'm not sure what 'there are more than the loop can handle in a single go' means, but why not just use an outer loop: `for array_list in new_arrays:` ?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I have 1 million observations that I need to loop over. The loop times out after about 100 thousand iterations. That is why I had to break it up into 10 different segments. But thank you for the idea, I will try it out.